# How to reference Windows.Networking (UWP functionality) from a .NET Core library

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm writing a .NET Core library which targets these frameworks:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.3": {},
  "uap10.0": {
    "buildOptions": { "define": [ "UWP" ] }
  }
}
```

However, I can't declare the following (compiler error "Networking does not exist in Windows namepspace"):

```
#if UWP
using Windows.Networking;
```

Windows.Networking works in a UWP app for me but I can't achieve the same in multi-target .NET Core library. Adding Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform dependency changes nothing:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.3": {},
  "uap10.0": {
    "dependencies": { "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2" },
    "buildOptions": { "define": [ "UWP" ] }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I ended up adding another UWP project, putting its csproj in the root of my project. Somehow, the same project.json worked fine for both .NET Core and UWP projects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146301/can-two-project-json-files-share-the-same-codebase

Comment: So you have resolved your issue in another thread, right?

Comment: Let's say, I managed to work around it. However, strictly speaking my current approach does not address the original question because I now have two projects instead of one. I'd better have a single .NET Core project with extra settings for UWP target.